# Using fOSUserName() in a table and form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am out of my league but trying to learn from this forum about `fOSUserName()` function.  I have it working in my form by using the following method.  Created a textbox in my form, in that textbox properties "Control Source" is: `=fOSUserName()`.  The textbox of course displays the current user.  What I want to know is how to place this information into a table. Since the "Control Source" is already populated with: `=fOSUserName()` I can't direct it to the field "UserID" with in the main table. I have tried setting `=fOSUserName()` as the default value in the textbox properties and made the control source point to the table but then nothing works.  I am using Access 2013.  I don't care about security as it is not needed.  I simply need a way to determine who is creating the record and record the value in a table.  It would be nice to have the name display on the form.  Ultimately, the record creator would be recalled an printed out similar to an invoice. Please assume I have very little knowledge when it comes to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the text box's Control Source to your `UserID` field.  And set the text box's Default Value to `=fOSUserName()`

Then when the form's current record is an existing row, the text box will display the stored `UserID` value.

But when the form is on the "new record", the text box will be loaded with the `fOSUserName` function's return value.  If you save the new record, that value will be stored.  But if you abort creation of the new record, that text box value will be discarded the same as any other value entered for that record.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm! Is it possible to compare the Username provide by the =fOSUserName() function against a list of names in a child table and record it's record ID number in the primary table?

Comment: Look at the Access help topic for the DLookup function.  Although I don't really understand your new goal, my hunch is that function could be useful.

Comment: For repetitive data I use combo boxes which I can select options from dedicated tables and only the ID# is recorded in the "main" table and want to do the same with "users" which I have about 13.  Currently, the actual UserName is recorded to the main table and is repetitive data. I would like to have only the UserID recorded to the "main table". What I need is for Fosusername() to determine who is using the database, compare that name against those listed in the user table and then save the matched UserID to the "main table". When I mean "UserID" I am referring to the autonumber of the table.

Comment: Did you investigate `DLookup`?  I'm thinking something like this might give you what you need: `DLookup("UserId", "users_table", "[UserName]='" & fOSUserName() & "'")`

Comment: Yes it works however it returns only the first record in the table.  Here is my syntax: =DLookUp("[Creator]","[tblCreator]","[Text92]='" & [Text92] & "'")

Comment: Text92 contains the current Username.

Comment: I do not understand what you want and suggest you submit a new question.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. My Creator table has 3 columns. Creator ID(autonumber),Creator(names) and Hash(alpha/numeric and where fosusername() should match at least one). There are 13 records. Record #5 is the one that should match but the dlookup returns the first record of the table not the fifth.

Comment: RESOLVED - I wasn't understanding that within the "criteria section" [Username] has to match the column header. Here is the working line: =DLookup("[Creator]", "[tblCreator]",  "[Creator Hash]='" & fOSUserName() & "'"). Thank you for staying with me and for all the help!